# WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 -

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, websocket

I am learning about websockets and followed the instructions here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

I' using tomcat v8.0.21 to deploy my webapp but get the following error

My JavaScript Project looks fine, when I visit the webapp: my localhost and visit WebSocketJavaScriptProject

Although in the console window get the error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/actions' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

My code lives here: https://github.com/darkcloudi/WebSocketProject

Difference between my app and the example on Oracle is I have split it as two projects one service and the other webapp.

I cannot figure out why I would be getting a 404 as the service .war file is called WebsocketHome. Any ideas what would be causing this issue? Usually a 404 is not found so guessing it cannot finding the service , i'm sure i'm doing something stupid but cannot figure out where the problem is

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you visit `ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/actions` via your browser ?

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome and get "This webpage is not available"

ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Error during the handshake happens, because Tomcat has its own api for websockets. Thus you might have added the JSR implementation or something similar as javax.websocket-api in your pom.xml there comes a conflict at runtime.

Try to not export your Websocket-library to your webserver, thus it uses its own implementation.

If you use maven, set the websocket dependency as provided:

```
<!-- Provided Websocket API, because tomcat has its own implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. So I tried what you suggested and it worked. Thanks :) I can see in the console that I get Status Code:101 Switching Protocols so thats good. But now get a different error in the logs (see below), need to look into why, main thing the service is running. 08-Jun-2015 20:40:31.276 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-13] org.example.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer.onError null
 java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Appears the first error is when its opening connection so need to do some more debugging. duffy - thanks again as I never realised that Tomcat had its own implementation. 08-Jun-2015 20:55:41.287 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-26] org.example.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer.onError null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.example.websocket.DeviceWebSocketServer.open(DeviceWebSocketServer.java:29)

Comment: This is the holy grail of answers. I've spent days finding this answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was added wesocket api jar and also add this jar in deployment assembly. But I should add websocket api for compile time usage but for runtime I need to remove from deployment assembly as TOMCAT server have already contain websocket api. Great help man thanks

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem. 
Try removing the unwanted jars which contains websocket in your $JAVA_HOME/lib folder.
and then add only what you are importing in serverendpoint file.

Comment: This isn't helpful.