# WebSocket connection to 'ws://*' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat8, java-websocket

You can find the all the code below,
started the tomcat server and It's perfectly working.
But While making websocket request I'm getting 404 error.
This is the error in chrome console :

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8088/websocket-example/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

and there is no server log.

Java WebSocket Code : WebSocketTest.java

```
package com.websockets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WebSocketTest {

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Message: " + message);
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello Mr. " + message);
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen() {
    System.out.println("Client connected");
}

@OnClose
public void onClose() {
    System.out.println("Connection closed");
}
}
```

JS Code : hello.html

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8088/websocket-example/websocket');
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Folder structure unders tomcat/webapps..

```
->webapps
     ->websocket-example
          ->hello.html
          ->WEB-INF
              ->classes
                  ->com
                      ->websockets
                          -> WebSocketTest.class
              ->web.xml
```

more info :

> java version "1.7.0_75"
>
> apache-tomcat-8.0.32
>
> server running port : 8088

I'm not sure this information is enough,Let me know any other details need to debug?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500998/websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500998/websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-404)

Answer (score 0):

Removed unwanted jars from $JAVA_HOME/lib.
and then added the javax.websocket-api-1.0-rc4.jar then It's working fine.