# Cannot connect to ServerEndpoint deployed in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, java, javascript, websocket

A lot of people assume that I use an IDE, so let me state this right now: *I do not use any IDE.*

---

I took the following Java source code, compiled it to `Echo.class`, then created `Echo.war` by writing `jar -cvf Echo.war Echo.class` in the Windows CMD, and uploaded the file inside `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` folder:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class Echo {

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String incomingMessage) {
        return "I recieved ('" + incomingMessage + "'), so I am returning it.";
    }
}
```

After starting Tomcat, I suddenly have the following folder structure:

```
<webapps>
    ...
    <Echo.war>
    <Echo>
        <Echo.class>
        <META-INF>
            <MANIFEST.MF>
        </META-INF>
    </Echo>
</webapps>
```

When trying to open a websocket connection to my endpoint via JavaScript with `new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8080/Echo/echo")`, I get a 404 response instead of a 101 handshake.

If it is to any help, here is a picture of what the manager shows: [image]

### (Tomcat 8 update):

I updated to Tomcat 8 following [this guide](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/install-and-configure-tomcat-8-on-centos-7/) and now `catalina.out` is no longer empty and the manager now shows this: [image]

Here are the contents of `catalina.out` that are too vast to be included in this post: http://pastebin.com/cwLviH5b

`Echo.war` is mentioned on lines `650`, `651`, `690`, and `691`.

---

I researched a bit and saw that if you build the class with Java 8 but your Tomcat is running on Java 7, you will get a `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. I didn't get that error, but I thought that I might as well update to Java 8 on my server. I did that and redeployed the WAR, but nothing changed.

I have also changed the annotation from `@ServerEndpoint("/echo")` to `@ServerEndpoint("/dest")` in case there was a name collision, but that didn't help either.

---

Here is a quote from [the book I am reading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071827196):

> Deploying your EchoServer WebSocket endpoint is particularly simple.
>   You need to compile the source file, include the class file in the WAR
>   file, and deploy the WAR file. The web container will detect that
>   there is a WebSocket endpoint included in the WAR file and do the
>   necessary setup to deploy it. Once you have completed these steps, you
>   are ready to make your first call to the WebSocket endpoint.

I took it that I have to create a WAR file with a single class file inside, but perhaps that is not the case, since he says *"the WAR file"* and not *"a WAR file"*.

And according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)#Content_and_structure), the WAR file *has to* contain a web.xml file (one might wonder why he didn't mention this). Is it true? Is this why it is not working? If it is, what should the web.xml contain? Surely it is not just an empty file with the name of "web.xml".

Comment: Sorry for typo, try with `/Echo/echo`

Comment: Check the logs files, verify if your war file is deploying correctly.

Comment: `<TOMCAT_HOME>/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: What are you using to compile the war?

Comment: Could you try doing a jar tf Echo.war and sharing what the output looks like?

Comment: @Ishmael `META-INF/`, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, `Echo.class`.

Comment: I'm completely baffled on why you don't use an IDE. Eclipse is free and fairly good. And there are other IDE options. Personally, I avoid the "wizards" because they tend to screw up things more than they help, but the IDE at least informs me of dumb mistakes and helps with auto-completion, etc. Good Luck to you.

Comment: @NickAllen I keep it at a lower level to learn what is actually going on. I might switch to an IDE at a later stage, but having that said, there are good programmers that stay away from IDEs as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create Following file structure

```
WEB-INF
  |
   - classes
        |
         - Echo.class
```

And create your war file by `jar -cvf echo.war *` from the parent folder of `WEB-INF`. Deploy this war file to tomcat and try connecting using web-socket.

Comment: Wow. This worked. Can you explain exactly why this works and what I did didn't work?

Comment: This works because that is the standard structure of a war-file with classes/resources in it. And if you have external libraries also then you shall put them in WEB-INF/lib. For complete information please see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove javax.websocket library from the build of your WAR file.

If you're using maven set the dependency to provided. For example:

```
<!-- Provided Websocket API, because tomcat has its own implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In Eclipse or IntelliJ you can set which libraries to export with your WAR.

Source:  [WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500998/websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-404)

Comment: I have searched the internet thoroughly. I have never in my life used an IDE and I do not use Maven. I create the .war by writing `jar -cvf Echo.war Echo.class` in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling the class? When you compile the class, dependent libraries must be in the class path. Those libraries must also be in WEB-INF/lib directory under the war deployment

Comment: The class is compiled with Java's websocket package in the classpath. However, you are not supposed to include the websocket library in your WAR because Tomcat has its own. My problem has been solved, though. Sanjeev's answer above was the solution.