# Using Maven, WebSocket connection to failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, websocket

I am trying to follow [this Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) in order to implement a basic websocket communication from an Angular powered Electron application to a Java powered backend deployed on a Tomcat 7.0.93 server using Maven 4.

I made sure that the frontend worked correctly using [an online websocket echo 
service](http://wss://echo.websocket.org). 
But when I want to connect it to my backend, I get the following error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9090/tests/gs-guide-websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`.

I am well aware that this question looks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30500998/6304206), but it is not :

- I made sure that the `javax.websocket-api` has a `provided` scope and thus the corresponding jar is not embedded on deployed server,
- I made sure that a [plain Tomcat + javax.websocket connection](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-websocket-tutorial/) is working on the given websocket URI, introducing Maven is breaking the solution, not Spring...

Do you guys have any idea of a possible solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was actually not related to a Maven dependency conflicting with Tomcat.

On a test-dedicated minimal server I was actually not reaching the correct endpoint, I finally managed to reach it.